# get know if request is subrequest of opening site or independent request to site

Tags: http

Is there any way to recognize (by process `http` packet or filtering `tcp` connections) does several requests belong to one opening url or another?

Try to explain in more detail. 
When we open any page in browser it also initializes different requests to download images, resources, scripts. I d like to get know that some scope of requests was invoked by opening site (call it main site). 
I can get `referer` property but in that case how to distinguish request to resorce from  request to different site link on which was clicked on main site. In both cases `referer` will be the same.
I suspect that this problem could not be resolved, but I hope that I'm mistaken. Or you can offer some workaround.

Comment: Or wfp, or driver? Edited tags.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this knowledge?

Comment: I'd like to filter package with wfp based on information what site opend and from what site request is going. But now it seems that i go in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the site, set a cookie or a URL parameter and check if it exists in subsequent requests.